# what waveform using to send qpsk signal with IQ tranceiver

Tags: qpsk, software-defined-radio

I have an SDR tranceiver (AD9361 on fmcomms3) working with IQ channels, i wanted to make a c++ software that modulate and send a digital QPSK signal but i'm a beginner in digital signal processing and i'm not sure what waveforms to inject into each of I and Q channel.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The book "Telecommunications Breakdown" (available for free http://sethares.engr.wisc.edu/telebreak.html) will help you figure out the signal shape. Interfacing with the fmcomms board can be done with either Matlab or GnuRadio.

Comment: I'm using libiio API to make my own application. I want to generate my qpsk signal by modifiying the example code found on: https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/master/examples/ad9361-iiostream.c